# How to get tokens in Jison?

Tags: javascript, parsing, token, lexer, jison

I'm using Jison for a college project, and I need to make a `switch` for each recognized token, so I can present to the professor something like:

```
<identifier, s>
<operator, =>
<identifier, a>
<operator, +>
<identifier, b>
```

Any way on how to get this done without recurring to regular expressions manually? (I mean, Jison uses regexp internally but that's not my business)

What I tried doing is the following:

```
var lex = parser.lexer,
    token;
lex.setInput('The code to parse');
while (!lex.done) {
    token = lex.next();
}
```

But the only thing I get saved in `token` is a number, and when a symbol is not defined in the grammar, it returns character-by-character token.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Warning: Some of this answer was derived by examining code generated by jison. Since the interfaces are not well defined, it may not stand the test of time.)

`parser.lexer.next()` is not part of the documented lexer interface, although the lexical analyzer produced by jison does appear to implement it. Note that it does not produce a token, if the input consumed corresponds to a lexical rule which does not produce a token. (For example, a rule which ignores whitespace.) It is better to use the documented interface `parser.lexer.lex()`, which does always produce a token.

Strictly speaking, `parser.lexer.lex()` is documented as returning the name of a terminal, but for efficiency the lexical analyzers generated by jison will return the internal numerical code for the terminal if `jison` is able to figure out which terminal the lexical rule will return. So you have a couple of alternatives, if you want to trace the actual names of the terminals recognized:

1. You can defeat this optimization by avoiding the use of the form `return <string>`. For example, if you change the lexical rule:

   ```
   [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]    { return 'IDENTIFIER`; }
   ```

   to

   ```
   [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]    { return '' + 'IDENTIFIER`; }
   ```

   then the generated lexical analyzer will return the string `'IDENTIFIER'` rather than some numeric code.
2. Alternatively, you can use `parser.terminals_`, which according to the comment at the top of the generated parser has the form `terminals_: {associative list: number ==> name}`, to look up the terminal name given the token number.

To get the source character string associated with the lexeme, use `parser.lexer.yytext`.

Here's a solution using the second alternative:

```
/* To reduce confusion, I change 'lex' to 'lexer' */
var lexer = parser.lexer,
    token;
lexer.setInput('The code to parse');
while (!lexer.done) {
    token = lexer.lex();
    /* Look up the token name if necessary */
    if (token in parser.terminals_) {
       token = parser.terminals_[token];
    }
    console.log('<' + token + ', ' + lexer.yytext + '>')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also had to look into generated parser source code in order to figure out, Jison documentation is still a bit deficient.
BTW I used the form you made :)